# Expectation of a Kernel Density Estimate with and without prior knowledge about Kernel

Tags: statistics, expected-value, density-function

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be iid. random variables from an unkown density $f$. The kernel density estimation at $x$ is then defined as
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(x;h) := \frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{x-X_i}{h}\right) 
\tag{1}\label{a}
\end{equation}
where $K$ is the kernel function that is a symmetric pdf centered around 0 and with bounded variance.

With the Gaussian Kernel
$$
K_G(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} x^2 \right)
$$
the equation (\ref{a}) can be rewritten as
$$
\hat{f}(x;h) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathcal{N}(x; X_i, h^2).\tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Now to my question. Let's take the expected value of Eq. (\ref{2}):
\begin{align}
E[\hat{f}(x;h)] &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[\mathcal{N}(x; X_i, h^2)] \\
 &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \tag{3}
\end{align}

Now, let's suppose we wouldn't have known that the Kernel used was the Gaussian kernel. Then the literature starts by taking the expected value for a single (???) random variable $Y$ like this:
\begin{align}
E[\hat{f}(x;h)] &= E \left[ \frac{1}{h} K\left(\frac{x - Y}{h}\right)  \right]\\
&= \int \frac{1}{h} K\left( \frac{x - y}{h}  \right) f(y) dy \\
&= \int \frac{1}{h} K(z) f(x - zh) h \text{d}z \\
         &= \int K(z) f(x -zh) \text{d}z. \tag{4}
\end{align}

My questions are:

1. how do Eq. (3) and Eq. (4) relate?
2. What's the matter with taking the expected value with regards to a single random variable $Y$? Or did I completely misunderstand that?

Here is a picture of the reference material where my second question stems from (note that $K_h(x) := \frac{1}{h}K(\frac{x}{h})$):
[Kernel Smoothing - Wand & Jones 1995](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9b4l.png). You can search for the book online and you can read it for free up to this point, i.e. page 14.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Did you find equation 3 in the book? Does it make sense to you.. since the $X_i$'s are the random variables, how can the expectation be a function of the $X_i$?

Comment: No, Eq. (3) comes from my brain, after I've read (and probably misunderstood) the comment [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/553290/can-you-take-the-expected-value-of-a-kernel-density-estimates) from Glen_b.
Sorry my math education is quite lacking, so I don't quite get your second question. My thought process was the following: I am taking the expected value of a Normal distribution, that is centered at $X_i$ and has variance $h^2$, therefore the expected value should be $X_i$ in my opinion.

Comment: please see my answer below, it should hopefully clarify what I meant in the comment

Comment: Yes it did clarify. One last question, was the comment by Glen_b linked above wrong then, too? Or did I misunderstand what he was trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your equation (3) is incorrect. When you take expectation you should be doing so with respect to the random variables $X_1,\dots, X_n$ which you assume are drawn i.i.d. with some density $f$. Therefore, in your line above eq (3) it should be

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{nh} \sum_{i=1}^n E_{X_i} [\mathcal{N}(x; X_i, h)]
= \frac{1}{h}E_{X_1} [\mathcal{N}(x; X_1, h)]
\end{align*}
because the $X_i$'s are i.i.d. Note that I am using the subscript to signify which variable the expectation is over and importantly, lowercase 'x' is FIXED. You seem to be treating the fixed quantity 'x' as a random variable. From here we have

$$
E_{X_1} [\mathcal{N}(x; X_1, h)] = \int \mathcal{N}(x; y,h) f(y) dy
$$
which requires knowledge of the density $f$ to compute.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I was really stuck and your explanation makes a lot of sense, I got it now!